# Условие в чанке, используя migx

Tags: modx, migx

**Как вывести контент в зависимости от значения вот этого поля**:

`{"caption":"Tab Title", "fields": [
{"field":"sectionType","caption":"Секция","inputTVtype":"listbox", "inputOptionValues":
"Изображение во весь экран==one-image
||Изображени Слева==image-info
||Изображени Справа==info-image"}`

**Вот чанк:**

```
[[*sectionType:is=`one-image`:then=`<div class="one-image">Work</div>`:else=`<h4>NOT WORK</h4>`]]
```

**и сам вывод:**

```
    [[getImageList? 
    &tvname = `sectionType` 
    &tpl = `@CODE: [[$Section]]`
    ]]
```

Пробовал добавлять чанки прямо в migx поле как написанно [тут](https://modxdevpro.ru/blog/revo/documentation/120-parameters-migx-getimagelist) - не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Приведённый вами json "Вкладки формы" не валиден. Должно быть примерно так:

```
[
{
    "caption":"Tab Title",
    "fields": [
        {
            "field":"sectionType",
            "caption":"Секция",
            "inputTVtype":"listbox",
            "inputOptionValues":
"Изображение во весь экран==one-image||Изображени Слева==image-info||Изображени Справа==info-image"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

**2.** В параметре `&tpl` достаточно указать просто *Section*

**3.** Обращаться в чанке к `sectionType` надо как к плэйсхолдеру.

Итого, вызов `getImageList`:

```
[[getImageList? 
    &tvname = `имя migx поля` 
    &tpl = `Section`
]]
```

Чанк **Section**:

```
[[+sectionType:is=`one-image`:then=`<div class="one-image">Work</div>`:else=`<h4>NOT WORK</h4>`]]
```